# Using a Win 7's Wamp 2.0i server from a Win XP Client

Tags: windows-xp, windows-7

I am now using a Windows 7 PC with a office Lan connected with 7 other PCs that are running Windows XP.

I installed Wamp Server 2.0i in my Windows 7 PC correctly. In my Windows 7 PC there is no problem to communicate with my localhost

My file sharing is on in my Win 7 PC. Anybody of my LAN can access the files using my PC name.

But when they want to access my localhost using http:// they can't communicate with my Win 7 localhost.

Please help me by informing how can I use the Win7 localhost from other Win XP PCs in my LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry. I made a mistake. I did not allow the Public Access in my Windows 7 firewall.

Those who will face the same problem, please allow access in your firewall.